# How do I bind a event to view from ViewModel in MvvmCross?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am new to MvvmCross , I have litle knowledge in Mvvm. Now I want to call a event in view xaml file from ViewModel. How can I do that? I found some solutions to do it from code behind, Is this possible from Xaml file?

Xaml content

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <dataForm:DataForm x:Name="dataForm" mvx:Bi.nd="DataObject ContactsInfo"/>
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MvxFormsPage : MvxContentPage<MvxFormsViewModel>
    {
        public MvxFormsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataForm.AutoGeneratingDataFormItem += DataForm_AutoGeneratingDataFormItem;
        }

        private void DataForm_AutoGeneratingDataFormItem(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.DataForm.AutoGeneratingDataFormItemEventArgs e)
        {
           //My code
        }
    }
```

I can able to bind my data model in xaml file and event in code behind, but I don't know how to bind event in xaml.

Comment: Would you post a demo so that we can test it for you? The demo using code behind is also OK.

Comment: Hi @AbbyWang-MSFT, I updated my code snippet. Can you please suggest me a solution?

Comment: so what you want is the `AutoGeneratingDataFormItem` to be subscribed in the ViewModel instead of in the View, or what do you mean by "bind event in xaml"?